# check item in array, if there print specific text in JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, input

So I have worked in IT for about 7 years now, however I never got into a position that involved a ton of coding. I like it to code, but am just a hobbyist at the moment, just to give you some understanding of my level of coding proficiency.

I am trying to create an HTML page that has some text before an input box, followed by a button. The button will perform a function on click, I want this function to take the input and run it against an array, if the item exists in the array, then I want it to print a specific message. This message is different for each item in the array.

To give you an idea of what I am doing, this is for my Dungeons and Dragons game, running the curse of strahd there is a part where a sequence of card draws are made to help you through the adventure. so say they draw a card, I put the word "Avenger" in the input box, it does exist in the array, I then want it to print "The treasure lies in a dragons house, in hands once clean, now corrupted." I know i could just write it all down, but i thought I would make a fun project of it. I have cobbled together what I think should work however when I press the button nothing happens.

```
<script>
    var LowCards ["avenger", "paladin",}
```

the array is there, populated with about 40 names, avenger, paladin, warrior, rogue, enchanter etc.

```
    function CARD1()
    {
        var card1 = document.getElementByID('card1').value;
        if(CARD1.indexOf("avenger") !== -1){
        alert("The treasure lies in a dragons house, in hands once clean, now corrupted.")
        } else if{CARD1.indexOf("paladin") !== -1){
        alert("I see a sleeping prince, a servant of light and the brother of darkness. The treasure lies 
        with him.")
        }
```

etc, etc, through the whole list of 40 until this last statement which says, if it isnt there tell them it doesnt exist.

```
        else{
        alert("Value does not exists!")
        }
    }
</script>
```

So the function is declared before the body, in the body I try to pull the fucntion with the button

```
<input type="text" id="card1" name="card1"=>Enter the name of the first card drawn</input>
<button onclick="CARD1();">Submit</button>
</p>
```

Comment: That input text mark up makes little sense

Comment: show complete code including html, css and javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is a little messed up.  indexOf will return positive number whenever the input is found in the array.  Thus only the first if statement will get executed.  The map function is a good way to go but if you are just starting out basic programming will do the trick.  Objects have keys and attributes.  Consider:

```
var LowCards = {avenger:"The treasure lies in a dragons house, in hands once
                clean, now corrupted.", paladin:"I see a sleeping prince, a 
                servant of light and the brother of darkness. The treasure 
                lies with him."};

avenger and paladin are keys and the associated text in quotes are the attributes.

var keys = Object.keys(LowCards);  
will get create an array called keys with each key.
```

```js
var LowCards ={avenger:"The treasure lies in a dragons house, in hands once clean, now corrupted.", paladin:"I see a sleeping prince, a servant of light and the brother of darkness. The treasure lies with him."};


    function CARD1()
    {
        var card1 = document.getElementById('card1').value;        
        var keys = Object.keys(LowCards);  
        var len = keys.length;
        
        
        for(let i = 0; i< len;i++){           
           if (card1 == keys[i]) {
              alert(LowCards[card1]);
              return;
           }   
        }
        
        alert("the value does not exist");
        return;
        
        
        
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="card1" name="card1">Enter the name of the first card drawn
<button onclick="CARD1();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I think this will work out for me, I really appreciate the explanation, just goes to show that I have yet a lot to learn specifically about javascript.

Comment: if the answer works please accept it so others know it's a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Let's double check your HTML:

```html
  <p>Type a card name and click submit</p> <!-- Make sure you have opening and closing tags -->
  <input type="text" id="card1" name="card1" /> <!-- Inputs are self-closing -->
  <button type="button" onclick="CARD1();">Submit</button> <!-- Give your button a type "button" to prevent any wacky default behavior -->
```

Another question: are you seeing console errors?  Especially I would suspect that you would see

```
Uncaught TypeError: CARD1.indexOf is not a function
```

If you're seeing that, I suspect that your problem is that you're declaring the variable name to be `card1`, but you're checking `CARD1.indexOf`.  (CAsing is imPORtant  )

Next, you've got a little confusion around how you're using `indexOf`. Basically, using `indexOf` is asking the question, "At what index is the value I'm passing found in the Array I'm calling off of?"  So, for example, `["avenger", "paladin"].indexOf("avenger")` will always return `0` (the zeroeth position in the Array).

I would suggest you graduate from your if/else chain up to a more advanced JS (and really programming in general) concept, the Map--which in JS is basically just an object.  Here's a simple solution:

```js
var textReceived = document.getElementById('card1').value;
// The variable name "textReceived" is more descriptive than "card1"
const cardTextMap = {
  avenger: 'The treasure lies in a dragons house, in hands once clean, now corrupted.',
  paladin: 'I see a sleeping prince, a servant of light and the brother of darkness. The treasure lies with him.',
  // ... all the other cards
};

// Now we'll check to see if the card name is found in the Object named "cardTextMap".
// We use square bracket notation instead of dot notation, because using square bracket
// allows us to pass a dynamic value as a key, i.e. the value of "textReceived"
if (cardTextMap[textReceived]) {
  // If we found a value inside of cardTextMap that matched what was typed,
  // e.g. cardTextMap.avenger (which can also be written `cardTextMap["avenger"]`),
  // then alert that value
  alert(cardTextMap[textReceived]);
} else {
  // If the user typed something that's not in the Map,
  // then cardTextMap[textReceived] will evaluate to `undefined` which
  // is "falsey" in JavaScript, so we'll fall into this else block:
  alert('Could not find the card you typed');
}
```

Comment: The developer tools of the browser say that LowCards was not defined and CARD1 was not defined.
So within the function i should use the var textReceived? I am going to type through my understanding of this:
textReceived is taking the data from the input by association of the id tag assigned to input "card1"
then the constants are declared per card
then I run the if else statement to print the text associated with the cardtextmap item
otherwise say it wasnt found
and this ties to the button, by setting button onclick="textReceived" or a function? sorry about my lack of understanding

Comment: I added some checks to the beginning of my answer; maybe making sure you've got good HTML markup will help?  Not sure where you're getting your console errors from if your function name is undefined 